# rails multiple after_save callbacks and entity.changes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a rails model in which I have defined a after_save callback and there is also an observer attached to this model having an after_save callback too.
What I have noticed is that after_save defined in model is getting called first and I can see the changed values in model through entity.changes in it.
However the callback in observer is showing no change in entity through entity.changes. 
If I however remove the first callback then I can changes through entity.changes even in observer's callback.
Is there a way I can get entity.changes in observer's callback without removing first callback in model ?

Comment: why are y0u suing an observer?

Comment: Unfortunately that observer is observing multiple models to do a common task on save event. Is there a way I can see entity.changes in the callback of observer ?

Comment: ok, I have not worked with observers, I just wanted to know why they are used. What is entity.changes? is entity the reference to a model? and changes from the module that track changes in ActiveRecord objects?

Comment: I suppose if entity is referncing model, then you could do entity.changes, so maybe I am not understanding something. Another thing you could do is to have a callback in the model and change multiple models on it, and remove the observer.